UE5 C++ build fails when creating character
I'm trying to learn how to create c++ class and use them for blueprint.
For AGameModeBase and AGameStateBase, it worked well. But when I create c++ file whose parent is ACharacter, editor fails to build and shows error.
This is my Live Coding Log.
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -ModuleWithSuffix=CppUnrealGame,7698 CppUnrealGameEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:/Users/USER/Documents/Unreal Projects/CppUnrealGame/CppUnrealGame.uproject" "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Unreal Projects/CppUnrealGame/CppUnrealGame.uproject"  -IgnoreJunk
Log file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
Building CppUnrealGameEditor...
Using Visual Studio 2022 14.40.33811 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Warning: Visual Studio 2022 compiler is not a preferred version
Determining max actions to execute in parallel (6 physical cores, 12 logical cores)
  Executing up to 6 processes, one per physical core
Using Parallel executor to run 5 action(s)
------ Building 5 action(s) started ------
[1/5] Compile [x64] LboxCharacter.cpp
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C3861: 'FMovementModeChangedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(33) : error C3861: 'FCharacterMovementUpdatedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(34) : error C3861: 'FCharacterReachedApexSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(35) : error C3861: 'FLandedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(41) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(117) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(176) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(239) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(238) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(241) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1045) : error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FCharacterAsyncOutput'
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
[2/5] Compile [x64] LboxCharacter.gen.cpp
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C3861: 'FMovementModeChangedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(33) : error C3861: 'FCharacterMovementUpdatedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(34) : error C3861: 'FCharacterReachedApexSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(35) : error C3861: 'FLandedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(41) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(117) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(176) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(239) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(238) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(241) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1045) : error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FCharacterAsyncOutput'
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75) : error C2665: 'ACharacter::ACharacter': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1047): note: could be 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const ACharacter &)'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const ACharacter &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const ACharacter &'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const ACharacter'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(244): note: or       'ACharacter::ACharacter(const FObjectInitializer &)'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const FObjectInitializer &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const FObjectInitializer &'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const FObjectInitializer'
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: while trying to match the argument list '(FVTableHelper)'
Total time in Parallel executor: 0.45 seconds
Total execution time: 1.19 seconds

I was doubt what the error is, so I turned off live coding and runned Uproject build provided by Rider IDE.
It also prints error:
CONSOLE: C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat  CppUnrealGameEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\CppUnrealGame.uproject" -WaitMutex 
0>Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
0>Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" CppUnrealGameEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\CppUnrealGame.uproject" -WaitMutex
0>Log file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
0>Building CppUnrealGameEditor...
0>Using Visual Studio 2022 14.40.33811 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
0>Warning: Visual Studio 2022 compiler is not a preferred version
0>Determining max actions to execute in parallel (6 physical cores, 12 logical cores)
0>  Executing up to 6 processes, one per physical core
0>Using Parallel executor to run 5 action(s)
0>------ Building 5 action(s) started ------
0>[1/5] Compile [x64] LboxCharacter.cpp
0>Character.h(32): Error C2143 : syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
0>Character.h(32): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(32): Error C3861 : 'FMovementModeChangedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(33): Error C3861 : 'FCharacterMovementUpdatedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(34): Error C3861 : 'FCharacterReachedApexSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(35): Error C3861 : 'FLandedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(41): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(117): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(176): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(239): Error C2143 : syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
0>Character.h(238): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(241): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(1045): Error C2061 : syntax error: identifier 'FCharacterAsyncOutput'
0>Character.h(1046): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(1046): Error C2143 : syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
0>[2/5] Compile [x64] LboxCharacter.gen.cpp
0>Character.h(32): Error C2143 : syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
0>Character.h(32): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(32): Error C3861 : 'FMovementModeChangedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(33): Error C3861 : 'FCharacterMovementUpdatedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(34): Error C3861 : 'FCharacterReachedApexSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(35): Error C3861 : 'FLandedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
0>Character.h(41): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(117): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(176): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(239): Error C2143 : syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
0>Character.h(238): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(241): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(1045): Error C2061 : syntax error: identifier 'FCharacterAsyncOutput'
0>Character.h(1046): Error C4430 : missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
0>Character.h(1046): Error C2143 : syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Error C2665 : 'ACharacter::ACharacter': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
0>Character.h(1047): Reference  : could be 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const ACharacter &)'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference  : 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const ACharacter &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const ACharacter &'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference Reason : cannot convert from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const ACharacter'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference  : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
0>Character.h(244): Reference  : or       'ACharacter::ACharacter(const FObjectInitializer &)'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference  : 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const FObjectInitializer &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const FObjectInitializer &'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference Reason : cannot convert from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const FObjectInitializer'
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference  : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
0>LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): Reference  : while trying to match the argument list '(FVTableHelper)'
0>Total time in Parallel executor: 0.41 seconds
0>Total execution time: 1.12 seconds

As I know, Character is extended Pawn. So I tried creating a Pawn instead of Character, and it worked.
Am I missing something like compiler version?
Environment

Windows 11 (21H2)
Intel i5-12400F
Unreal Engine 5.4.2
Jetbrains Rider 2024.1.4
Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.10.3)

==== EDIT: After installing MSVC build tools 14.36-17.6 ====
Still getting error building it:
Log          None                      Candidate modules for hot reload:
Log          None                        CppUnrealGame
Log          None                      Launching UnrealBuildTool... [C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.4/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -ModuleWithSuffix=CppUnrealGame,2721 CppUnrealGameEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:/Users/USER/Documents/Unreal Projects/CppUnrealGame/CppUnrealGame.uproject" "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Unreal Projects/CppUnrealGame/CppUnrealGame.uproject"  -IgnoreJunk]
Warning      None                      Starting HotReload took  0.0s.
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -ModuleWithSuffix=CppUnrealGame,2721 CppUnrealGameEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:/Users/USER/Documents/Unreal Projects/CppUnrealGame/CppUnrealGame.uproject" "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Unreal Projects/CppUnrealGame/CppUnrealGame.uproject"  -IgnoreJunk
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Log file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Creating makefile for CppUnrealGameEditor (BuildConfiguration.xml is newer)
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Building CppUnrealGameEditor...
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Using Visual Studio 2022 14.38.33139 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Determining max actions to execute in parallel (6 physical cores, 12 logical cores)
Log          CompilerResultsLog          Executing up to 6 processes, one per physical core
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Using Parallel executor to run 15 action(s)
Log          CompilerResultsLog        ------ Building 15 action(s) started ------
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [1/15] Resource Default.rc2
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [2/15] Compile [x64] SharedPCH.UnrealEd.Project.ValApi.Cpp20.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [3/15] Compile [x64] LboxCharacter.gen.cpp
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C3861: 'FMovementModeChangedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(33) : error C3861: 'FCharacterMovementUpdatedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(34) : error C3861: 'FCharacterReachedApexSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(35) : error C3861: 'FLandedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(41) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(117) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(176) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(239) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(239) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(241) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1045) : error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FCharacterAsyncOutput'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75) : error C2665: 'ACharacter::ACharacter': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1047): note: could be 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const ACharacter &)'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const ACharacter &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const ACharacter &'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const ACharacter'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(244): note: or       'ACharacter::ACharacter(const FObjectInitializer &)'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: 'ACharacter::ACharacter(const FObjectInitializer &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const FObjectInitializer &'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'FVTableHelper' to 'const FObjectInitializer'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
Log          CompilerResultsLog        C:\Users\USER\Documents\Unreal Projects\CppUnrealGame\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UnrealEditor\Inc\CppUnrealGame\UHT\LboxCharacter.gen.cpp(75): note: while trying to match the argument list '(FVTableHelper)'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [4/15] Compile [x64] LboxCharacter.cpp
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(32) : error C3861: 'FMovementModeChangedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(33) : error C3861: 'FCharacterMovementUpdatedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(34) : error C3861: 'FCharacterReachedApexSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(35) : error C3861: 'FLandedSignature_DelegateWrapper': identifier not found
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(41) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(117) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(176) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(239) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<class-head>'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(239) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(241) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1045) : error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FCharacterAsyncOutput'
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error        CompilerResultsLog        C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Classes\GameFramework\Character.h(1046) : error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [5/15] Compile [x64] CppUnrealGame.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [6/15] Compile [x64] CppUnrealGame.init.gen.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [7/15] Compile [x64] LboxGameState.gen.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [8/15] Compile [x64] LboxGameState.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [9/15] Compile [x64] LboxGamemode.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [10/15] Compile [x64] LboxGamemode.gen.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [11/15] Compile [x64] LboxPawn.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        [12/15] Compile [x64] LboxPawn.gen.cpp
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Total time in Parallel executor: 27.81 seconds
Log          CompilerResultsLog        Total execution time: 29.98 seconds
Log          LogMainFrame              MainFrame: Module compiling took 30.521 seconds
Warning      None                      HotReload failed, recompile failed
Log          LogDerivedDataCache       C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/UnrealEngine/Common/DerivedDataCache: Maintenance finished in +00:00:00.000 and deleted 0 files with total size 0 MiB and 0 empty folders. Scanned 0 files in 1 folders with total size 0 MiB.

I edited C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\UnrealBuildTool\BuildConfiguration.xml too.

Please change your regional settings to English, so you get your error messages in English that most of us here can read and understand.

I have edited the logs. Does it look fine now?

Wild guess: one of your own classes is missing a semicolon after the definition. Start at "LboxCharacter.cpp" and work your way backwards through your headers.

I haven't edited anything in the file after I created it. It only contains generated codes by unreal engine or rider. This is LboxCharacter.cpp

What does your LboxCharacter.h header file look like?

It is auto generated code too. LboxCharacter.h

There could be thousands of different reasons for an error like this. It's highly unlikely that it's caused by UE or its code-generators, which unfortunately leaves you as the one responsible for the error. What changes have you done recently? Did it work before those changes? What are the changes you have made, and where?

I don't think I did something to influence this. I created some input things like Input Mapping Context in Content/App/Core and Content/Input/Action. And then created "LboxGameMode", "LboxGameState" cpp/h in C++ Classes/CppUnrealGame/Private/Core.
And then I tried to create Character like other cpp classes, right clicking Core directory and Add-Unreal Class... in Rider, but it outputs error unlike the others. Note that my project name is "CppUnrealGame".

If you really didn't modify any generated code, ask in the Unreal forums. The real Unreal experts are there, not here.

Please, try installing the MSVC v 143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.38-17.8) component from Visual Studio installer.
Then set compiler version to newly installed compiler in BuildConfiguration.xml (for ex, in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\UnrealBuildTool):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="https://www.unrealengine.com/BuildConfiguration">
    <WindowsPlatform><CompilerVersion>14.38.33130</CompilerVersion>
        </WindowsPlatform>
</Configuration>

